# Java Code - Why a variable is being cloned here?

Tags: java, immutability, code-snippets

Look at the following code which i am copying from **javax.naming.InitialContext**. An argument of HashTable type is being passed to the constructor. here is the code snippet

```
public InitialContext(Hashtable<?,?> environment) throws NamingException
{
    if (environment != null) {
        environment = (Hashtable)environment.clone();
    }
    init(environment);
}
```

My question is, why environment is being cloned here when it could have been passed directly to init method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is protecting itself from an external caller changing the state of the `HashTable`.

By making a `clone` of it, they ensure that changes made to the `Hashtable` that was passed in are not reflected inside of the method/object the table was passed into.

A short example using arrays:

```
//Outside code
int[] arr = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3};

// method of class
public void init(int[] arr) {
    this.arr = arr; 
}

//meanwhile, in the external code
arr[0] = 42; // this change to the array will be reflected inside the object.
```

That vulnerability can be avoided by making a copy of the array.  Changes to the original array will not show up in the copy.

Comment: I think I'd reword your first sentence to "This code is protecting *itself* from an external caller changing the state of the HashTable." Although it's a very limited protection, given that H`ashtable.clone()` is a shallow clone: the caller could still change mutable values (I can't remember whether context values are limited to strings or not).

Comment: @Anon, the chances are good that the only thing they are worried about are additions or removals.  They are probably using immutable objects as keys or values.

Answer (score 2):

Because it could be changed from the outside of this method?